# Grails 3.2.9 SQL Driver error

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-orm, grails3

After upgrading from Grails 3.2.5 to 3.2.9 I started receiving the SQL Server driver exception (using sqljdbc42.jar):

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The database name component of the object qualifier must be the name of the current database.
```

After downgrading to Grails 3.2.7 this stopped again.  I am calling a Stored Procedure in different DB but the code works in 3.2.7 and before and not in 3.2.9.  I tried upgrading the SQL Server JDBC version to the value below with to no avail.

`compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.1.7.jre8-preview'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails 3.2.9 includes Groovy 2.4.10 which is an upgrade from Groovy 2.4.7.  I see issues in Groovy Sql in Groovy 2.4.10 that did not exist in 2.4.7 (which is what I was using with Grails 3.2.7).  Hope this is helpful to someone else looks to be fixed in Groovy 2.4.11 which might end up in Grails 3.2.10.  Below is a URL to the issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8128

Answer (score 0):

Get the name of the database by running this SQL query

```
SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases;
```

Compare it with the database name configured in `application.yml`

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:<port>/<database name>
```

This problem is occurred for case sensitivity issue as I thing. So check Microsoft SQL database name (case sensitive) and your given database name is exactly same.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that does not seem to be the problem.  I looked into the name on the Server based on other people having a related problem and verified the case on the DB name.  Why did this happen when going from Grail 3.2.5 to Grails 3.2.9?  Going back to Grails 3.2.7 resolved the problem.